# Java: A client/server file transfer (incomplete files)

Tags: java, multithreading, file-transfer, serversocket

I am building an application that will send file across the network through sockets.

There are 2 programs. Server and Client each have two classes Download and Upload.

```
 public class Download implements Runnable{

        public ServerSocket server;
        public Socket socket;
        public int port;
        public String saveTo = "";
        public InputStream In;
        public FileOutputStream Out;

        public Download(String saveTo){
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(1544);
                port = 1544;
                this.saveTo = saveTo;            
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception [Download : Download(...)]");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = server.accept();
                In = socket.getInputStream();
                Out = new FileOutputStream(saveTo);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while((count = In.read(buffer)) >= 0){
                    Out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                Out.flush();
                if(Out != null){ Out.close(); }
                if(In != null){ In.close(); }
                if(socket != null){ socket.close(); }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and class Upload:

```
public class Upload implements Runnable{
    public String addr;
    public int port;
    public Socket socket;
    public FileInputStream In;
    public OutputStream Out;
    public File file;
    public Upload(String addr, int port, File filepath){
        super();
        try {
            file = filepath;
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1545);
            Out = socket.getOutputStream();
            In = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception [Upload : Upload(...)]");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {       
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            while((count = In.read(buffer)) >= 0){
                Out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            Out.flush();
           if(In != null){ In.close(); }
            if(Out != null){ Out.close(); }
            if(socket != null){ socket.close(); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the class server:

```
 File myFile = new File("temp");
 Upload upl = new Upload("temp", 1544,myFile)
 fileThreadSend = new Thread(upl);
 fileThreadSend.start();
```

and in class client:

```
 Download dwn = new Download("temp");
 Thread fileThread = new Thread(dwn);
 fileThread.start();
```

the problem runs but it doesn't transfer all the file 
sometimes it transfer just 9kb of it and sometimes 20 MBS.
what is wrong?
I tried to search but couldn't find applicable any solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be a typo - but isn't your Upload class always creating a socket on port 1545 and ignoring the passed in port parameter?  If it's not a typo - you might be Uploading to a different port than you thought.  For what it's worth - the code transfers fine on my machine (client and server running on the same machine), although it doesn't close sockets cleanly on error.  I wonder whether something can interrupt one of the threads?  Are you testing client and server on the same machine, or different?

Comment: No you are right it's a typo, in the complete program it's a the same port on both sides.

i am testing on the same machine.

Comment: OK - well - I can't make it fail in that scenario (i.e. can't reproduce failure).  Do you get any exceptions when only part of the file is copied?  Is there a reason you want to implement your own client server solution via your own Thread implementation working with sockets directly?

Comment: No reason. It's just the way i stumbled upon and understood so i implemented it so if you have a another solution it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Don't be bothered and use what the JDK has to offer:

- [create a file from an `InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-);
- [send the contents of a file to an `OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.io.OutputStream-).

More details [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API). And don't forget to use try-with-resources.

Also, avoid using `Thread` directly and use an `ExecutorService` instead.

Comment: could you provide please a very short example of using copy.

Thant would be much appreciated

Comment: Uh, doesn't the provided link on the API usage provide you enough information?